# Fedora-GRUB in Mint

Tags: fedora, linux-mint, grub2

I want to install the GRUB2-Layout of Fedora in Mint.

(I'm a new user, so I can't upload images. :( The image is here: http://ryanlerch.fedorapeople.org/Selection_045.png)

Does anybody know, how I can do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is Fedora `beefymiracle` GRUB2 theme. I'm not using Mint so no idea if that is available from Mint repos. If it is, install it. If it's not in the repos, get it from [here](http://linuxgrrl.com/temp/grub2-f17/beefymiracle-grub2-theme.tar.gz). Unpack the archive, inside you will find a folder named `beefymiracle` (containing all theme files), place it in `/usr/share/grub/themes/`. Next, change GRUB theme:
Open (as root or sudo) `/etc/default/grub` and look for a line containing `GRUB_THEME`. Edit like this:

```
GRUB_THEME="/usr/share/grub/themes/beefymiracle/theme.txt"
```

save, then run:

```
update-grub
```

or

```
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

Works on my Archlinux install.

Comment: in my `/etc/default/grub` is no line with `GRUB_THEME`...
There are only the following lines:

**`GRUB_DEFAULT=0
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR='lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian'
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""`**

should I create that line anyway?